# Pass rotation event through UIWindow and UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia-substrate

Here is psuedo code for my tweak

```
SBSearchViewController vcont = ...;
UIWindow window = ...;
[window retain];
window.windowLevel = 9999*9999;
window.hidden = NO;
window.rootViewController = vcont;
[window addSubview:vcont.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When there is a rotation event the keyboard successfully rotates but the actual contents of the UIWindow does not. This is a [common problem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html) but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
[window addSubview:vcont.view];
```

Comment: Did you also assign the window to a `strong` property? If you don't retain the window it will be deallocated immediately

Comment: Didn't work. I'm using SBSearchGesture to do the animations/rotation